# xQuery: Check for string in element but ignore multiple elements within the same element but with different values

Tags: string, xquery, contains

Okay, so I have this movie xml file that contains two movies. I want to get all movies that contain the 'Action' string.

```
<movie id="19995">
    <genre genre_id="28">Action</genre>
    <genre genre_id="12">Adventure</genre>
    <genre genre_id="14">Fantasy</genre>
    <vote_average>7.2</vote_average>
</movie>

<movie id="19995">
    <genre genre_id="14">Fantasy</genre>
    <genre genre_id="878">Science Fiction</genre>
    <vote_average>7.2</vote_average>
</movie>
```

This is my code atm.

```
let $xml_file := doc("tmdb_5000_movies")
let $action_movies := $xml_file//movie[contains(genre/text(), 'Action')]
```

But I get the following error message.

```
[XPTY0004] Item expected, sequence found: (text {"Action"}, text {"Adventure"}, ......
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`contains()` indeed takes one item; but since each movie in the xml has two or more genres, `contains` encounters a sequence of two or three items, resulting in the error message.

Try it this way:

```
let $action_movies := $xml_file//movie

return  $action_movies[genre[contains(text(),'Action')]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the v v quick response, I appreciate that! It worked great :)